# Correct?: To come upon such positive resonance

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality, word-usage, translation

I am trying to find a good translation for the German

> Auf eine positive Resonanz stoßen

Can one say

> Something comes upon such positive resonance

when I want to express that something is replied with a positive response (and want to somehow emphasize that).

Comment: It  was  met with a very positive response!!

Comment: To be glad that something meets with a positive response. Would that be correct?

Comment: You probably mean..I am glad that it is met with a positive response!

Answer (score 1):

A better, more idiomatic way to say this would be to drop the *positive* altogether, as that will be implied in the following:

> [The thing in question] **resonated strongly with** [the audience for it].